# I have a problem To Access And Count Sent Mails Using Imaplib

Tags: python, email, count, imaplib

Here is the code (Already Imported The Library) :

```
mail.select('"[Gmail]/Sent Mail"')
typ,messageIds = mail.search(None,"SEEN")
messageIdsString = str(messageIds[0],encoding='utf-8')
listofmessages = messageIdsString.split(" ")
nbr = len(listofmessages)
if len(listofmessages)== 0:
    print("You Have No Mails On Inbox")
elif len(listofmessages)== 0:
    print("You Have No Mails On Spam")
else :
    print("You Have ",nbr,"New Emails Inbox")
```

I Don't Know What To Do If Anyone Can Help Please

Comment: What is the problem? Do you get wrong number ? Do you get error message? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe first you should use `print()` to see what you get in variables. OR maybe Gmail use different values then any other mail server. As I know it may keep all files in one folder and use `tags` to display then as folders - even for standard folders.

Comment: or maybe you should use other module - like [IMAPClient](https://imapclient.readthedocs.io/) or [imap-tools](https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools)

Comment: you check the same `len(listofmessages)== 0:` in `if` and `elif` - so you will never see message for `Spam`. And you check folder `Send Mail` but you display message `Inbox`

Comment: when I assign to variable `result = mail.select('"[Gmail]/Sent Mail"')` and display `result` then I see `('NO', [b'[NONEXISTENT] Unknown Mailbox: [Gmail]/Sent Mail (Failure)'])`

Comment: using `mail.list()` I found it uses name in my native language (Polish) `"[Gmail]/Wys&AUI-ane"` (`[GMail]/Wysłane`) - maybe you has similar problem.

Comment: I Want To Select and Count How Much email has been sent using Imaplib if AnyOne Could Help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is your problem - you didn't describe details - but when I tested this code

```
result = mail.select('"[Gmail]/Sent Mail"')

print(result)
```

then it show see

```
('NO', [b'[NONEXISTENT] Unknown Mailbox: [Gmail]/Sent Mail (Failure)'])
```

Using this code to display all folder

```
result = mail.list()

for folder in result[1]:
    print( folder.decode('utf-8') )
```

I found that I don't have `[Gmail]/Sent Mail` but in native language (Polish) `"[Gmail]/Wys&AUI-ane"` (which I see in GMail as `[GMail]/Wysłane`). The same problem I have for folders `Draft`, `Spam/Junk`, `Trash`,  - so maybe you have similar problem with different name.

Using `mail.list()` and flag `\\Sent`, `\\Drafts`, `\\Junk`, `\\Trash` I can get my native name for these folders.

```
def detect_names():
    """Detect native names for standard folders (using flags)."""

    keys = {
        #'\\Inbox': 'INBOX',
        '\\Sent': 'SENT',
        '\\Drafts': 'DRAFTS',
        '\\Junk': 'JUNK',
        '\\Trash': 'TRASH',
        '\\Important': 'IMPORTANT',
        '\\All': 'ALL',
    }
    
    result = {
        'INBOX': 'INBOX',
        'SENT': None,
        'DRAFTS': None,
        'JUNK': None,
        'TRASH': None,
        'IMPORTANT': None,
        'ALL': None,
    }
     
    data = mail.list()

    for folder in data[1]:
        all_flags, name = folder.decode('utf-8').split(' "/" ')
        for flag, key in keys.items():
            if flag in all_flags:
                result[key] = name
                
    return result
```

---

And here full code which I used for test

```
import imaplib
import getpass

def display_folders():
    """Display all folders (with native names) and flags."""
    
    result = mail.list()
    #print('[DEBUG] (mail.list) result:', result)

    for folder in result[1]:
        print(folder.decode('utf-8'))
        #flags, name = folder.decode('utf-8').split(' "/" ')
        #print(flags, name)
    
def detect_names():
    """Detect native names for standard folders (using flags)."""

    keys = {
        #'\\Inbox': 'INBOX',
        '\\Sent': 'SENT',
        '\\Drafts': 'DRAFTS',
        '\\Junk': 'JUNK',
        '\\Trash': 'TRASH',
        '\\Important': 'IMPORTANT',
        '\\All': 'ALL',
    }
    
    result = {
        'INBOX': 'INBOX',
        'SENT': None,
        'DRAFTS': None,
        'JUNK': None,
        'TRASH': None,
        'IMPORTANT': None,
        'ALL': None,
    }
     
    data = mail.list()

    for folder in data[1]:
        all_flags, name = folder.decode('utf-8').split(' "/" ')
        for flag, key in keys.items():
            if flag in all_flags:
                result[key] = name
                
    return result

def test(names):
    """Check number of mails in `Sent`."""

    #result = mail.select('"[Gmail]/Sent Mail"')
    #result = mail.select('"[Gmail]/Wys&AUI-ane"')

    result = mail.select(names['SENT'])
    #print('[DEBUG] (mail.select) result:', result)

    # - SEEN -
    
    typ, msg_ids = mail.search(None, 'SEEN')
    #print('[DEBUG] (mail.search) result:', result)

    number_SEEN = len(msg_ids[0])
    print('number SEEN:', number_SEEN)

    # - ALL -
        
    typ, msg_ids = mail.search(None, 'ALL')
    #print('[DEBUG] (mail.search) result:', result)

    number_ALL = len(msg_ids[0])
    print('number ALL :', number_ALL)

    # - diff - 
    
    diff = number_ALL - number_SEEN
    print('       diff:', diff)

    #for num in msg_ids[0].split():
    #    typ, data = mail.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
    #    print('Message ', num)
    #    #print(data[0][1])

    mail.close()
    
# --- main ---

login = input('Login: ')
password = getpass.getpass()

# --- 

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com', 993)
mail.login(login, password)

# - folders -

print('\n--- folders ---\n')
display_folders()

# - native names -

names = detect_names()

print('\n--- native names ---\n')
for key, name in names.items():
    print(f'{key:9} ---> {name}')

# - test - 

print('\n--- test ---\n')

test(names)

# - end -
    
mail.logout()
```

---

**BTW:**

Module [IMAPClient](https://imapclient.readthedocs.io) has function for this

```
client.find_special_folder(imapclient.imapclient.SENT))
```

Comment: Yes I Found That The Problem is in My Native Language thank you sm for your Help I rexommand to use the code to display all folder and then use the text showen